# How to pass arguments to a executable created by C program?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, executable

Command line arguments? How to execute the exe from DOS and pass arguments?

Comment: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about

> How to execute the exe from DOS and pass arguments?

then

- open command prompt
- Navigate to the directory where your C generated executable is located,using `cd` command
- write the name of your executable on prompt, lets suppose abc.exe followed by space seperated arguments
  Ex:-

  `abc.exe Param1 Param2 Param3`
- Hit Enter

> If you want to execute from C

then follow [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar)